# font icon not displaying in ajax in html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, tabs, font-awesome

I have a tab like below and I am trying to display results through ajax inside this tab, in each tab content I have added ordered list and font icon as below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("ol li").prepend("<i class='fa fa-check-square-o' style='margin-right:10px;'></i>");
    $(".tabcontent p").prepend("<i class='fa fa-check-square-o' style='margin-right:10px;'></i>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="exTab1">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Inclusions</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Description</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">Points To Note</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">Terms</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3a">

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="4a">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here the problem is only ordered list is coming and the font icon is not displaying.

Can anyone please tell me what wrong did I do here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you add cdn for fontawesome ?

Comment: @Swati yes, i have

Comment: check your browser element tabs if the element which you are adding is added or not . Also , its ol or ul ?

Comment: @Swati i checked, the <ol><li> is coming fine, but font icon is not

Comment: Your provided jquery code works fine you can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5td7n2j8/) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't  understand properly but I try, you write wrong class in jQuery is ="tabcontent" instead of "tab-content". and second is you use "ul" in tag  and you use "ol" in jQuery

"Code Snippet" is not load js property that's why I use codepen.(I delete pen after you show it.)

https://codepen.io/Lucifer18/pen/abBJXRa

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("ul li").prepend("<i class='fa fa-check-square-o' style='margin-right:10px;'></i>");
$(".tab-content ").prepend("<i class='fa fa-check-square-o' style='margin- 
right:10px;'></i>");});
```